# How to disable Settings link?

Tags: profile, security, configuration, disable

I am looking for disable the "Settings" option displayed in salesforce when clicking in the user circle for specific profiles.

[image]

Thank you all!

Comment: Apologies for my curiosity but why would you need that. Settings are like Profile settings where user can change the way he interacts with Salesforce, unique to each user and user-configurable. Is there a specific reason to disallow that?

Comment: In my case the environment will be configured by an administrator and no other profile will be able to change any configuration.

Comment: Well, this can be controlled in communities but not with Standard Salesforce license/UI

Comment: Thank you @manjit5190 Is this documented in any reference site? I haven't found it

Comment: No, but you can always raise a case with Support to get an answer if you want to document it somewhere.